# Installing GWT Developer Plugin on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, gwt

I have a sample app in GWT. When I run it and open in my Firefox - the browser still displays this:

[image: gwtBrowser]

Even if GWTP Developer plugin is sucessfully installed

[image: pluginInstalled]

My Firefox version is 25.0 (on Fedora 20), I know that the new versions of Firefox have problem with GWT plugin, but this version should be probably ok. What is the problem?

Comment: You may install an earlier version of firefox, or try with another browser (chrome).

Comment: GWT Developer Plugin no longer works with Chrome on Linux: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Ve32_oy0kAw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known problem. Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8423

The solutions proposed there are to either:

- download a special [plugin](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-dev-plugin-1-25-1-rc1.xpi) that they've made for this bug
- yum removing firefox and xulrunner and installing Firefox 25 from
  ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/25.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/
- You can also try upgrading to firefox 26, as the support was removed
  in 27 and 26 should work fine with the normal plugin.